# Collision with projectile causing SceneManager to LoadScene

Tags: c#, 2d, collision

Thank you in advance for any input.

What is essentially happening is this: When the player shoots, the scene resets

What I interpret as happening:

1. Player shoots a laser beam
2. Laserbeam prefab collides immediately with player (so far as I can tell)
3. SceneManager resets scene

I suspect two possible causes:

1. Either the origin of my laserbeam is causing the created projectilePrefab to trigger the player's collision in this piece of code:

   private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
   {
   SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
   //if collider is projectile.Prefab, don't run this piece of code
   }
2. More generally that my laserbeam collision doesn't exclude the player gameobject:

   ```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            var projectile = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                transform.position,
                projectilePrefab.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
   ```

The typical solutions then would likely look like this:

1. Ensure the laserbeam spawns away from the player, so they do not collide.

or, ideally,

2. The collider on my player would be able to simply exclude contact with a laserbeam as cause for SceneManager to reset the scene.

Where I get stuck when it comes to testing these solutions is the exact syntax. I was hoping someone might be willing to give some insight that is adept at conditional statements and the like. I'm still super new, so while I can largely comprehend what I'm reading and being shown, I'm still stuck before that hump of really being able to dissect it all myself.

Essentially what my ideal might look like (so far as I can tell) is: "If collider is projectilePrefab, do not run SceneManager.LoadScene"

Cheers and thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could use layer-based collision detection https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: That was recommended multiple times on Unity's forum, but I was trying to make a conditional solution work that could be more generally applied. I'll at least try it this way and see if I can't get it working before I attempt more complex solutions though.